# resource in mysql_connect in php

Tags: php, mysql-connect

I am trying to connect to database through php.I did it lots of time. But I want to know how many rows exist in my table.
I've tried to use php manual, however, I was confused.

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);
```

The above code worked on :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

But when I decided to use

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password","database");
```

It occurred an error like this:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ...
```

What is difference between codes? And how can I solve it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: use mysqli instead of mysql, and u can not pass database in mysql_connect statement `mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password","database");`..

Answer (score 2):

The 4th parameter to `mysql_connect` is supposed to be a `boolean` type indicating whether you always want a new connection (even if `mysql_connect` was called earlier), not a string. As a result, `$link` is `false` because `mysql_connect` failed.

[PHP documentation on mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: and the 4th parameter is not supposed to be the database name

Answer (score 0):

selecting DB as 4th parameter in mysql_connect is wrong - the functions returns *false* and no mysql_num_rows() following is possible

Answer (score 0):

The mysql_connect function accept 5 arguments. In that in 4th argument this should be either true or false. But you have passed the string. This is not correct. you cann't pass the database name here.

For more tutorial [see here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) and also [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_mysql_connect.asp#gsc.tab=0).

Answer (score 0):

You can not select database by  `mysql_connect()` function. This function is used to connect to the database, not to query the database. To query the database use `mysql_select()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

this parameters are allowed in   mysql_connect

```
mysql_connect(server,user,pwd,newlink,clientflag)
```

please check http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_connect.asp